# kotlin field is not set the value

Tags: kotlin

here is my kotlin code for android。kotlin version is 1.2.41

```
    private fun getUserFromSharePreferences() {

    Timber.d("getSP() = ${getSP()}")  // sharedPreferences
    Timber.d("sp = ${sp}")  // null
    }


    private fun getSP() = CoreApplication.context.getSharedPreferences(FLAG_SP_USER, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    private val sp = CoreApplication.context!!.getSharedPreferences(FLAG_SP_USER, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)!!
```

use "sp" get null.
use "getSP()" get object

---

here is decompiled code

```
public final class UserKt {
   private static User currentUser = getUserFromSharePreferences();
   private static final SharedPreferences sp;




   private static final void getUserFromSharePreferences() {
      Timber.d("getSP() = " + getSP(), new Object[0]);
      Timber.d("sp = " + sp, new Object[0]);
   }

   private static final SharedPreferences getSP() {
      return CoreApplication.context.getSharedPreferences("FLAG_SP_USER", 0);
   }

   static {
      Context var10000 = CoreApplication.context;
      if(CoreApplication.context == null) {
         Intrinsics.throwNpe();
      }

      SharedPreferences var0 = var10000.getSharedPreferences("FLAG_SP_USER", 0);
      if(var0 == null) {
         Intrinsics.throwNpe();
      }

      sp = var0;
   }
}
```

why use "sp" get the null?
is kotlin bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No bug. All `init` blocks and property initializers run in the given order, and you put `sp` at the end, as you can see in the decompiled code.

As a side note, making `Context` and `SharedPreferences` static (in case of Kotlin, putting them into an `object`) is a bad idea in Android development.

Comment: thanks
i change code like this

```
    private val sp = //..

    private fun userSP(){
       //...
    }
```

Comment: @user9214779 That won't work in comments, use single backticks only :)